# Proxied request gets bounced interceptor

Tags: spring-boot

I have an api gateway which redirects requests to appropiate services, based on the context.
When I proxy the DELETE request to logout from the gateway to the authService, it is getting filtered by the interceptor and a 415 error is showing.

Apparently the excludePatterns is not working or the proxied request has something different that does not fit into the excluded pattern.

I'm proxying like this:

> HttpUriRequest proxyRequest = createHttpRequest(request, serviceUrl);

It works with login and POST. It works without the gateway, directly, using postman. There is absolutely no difference in the serviceURL the gateway is sending and the URL postman sends directly to authService.

The method above creates an appropiate request with headers and content.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
The interceptor is looking for an exact match of pathVariables or requestParam variables, otherwise, it intercepts it.